# Convert innerHTML into a custom json with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, innerhtml

This is an example of innerHTML i get from a text editor on a web page where user can write text and add images, videos and audios.

```
<p>This is a<br>test</p>
<p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/12345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
<p><audio controls><source src="https://www.test.com/123/456/example.mp3"/></audio></p>
<p>end of test</p>
```

I save the innerHTML so i can reload the contents written by the user inside the editor, but i also need to format those information in json structure like the following:

```
{
  "page1": {
     contents: [
        {"text":"This is a test"},
        {"video":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/12345"},
        {"audio":"https://www.test.com/123/456/example.mp3"},
        {"text":"end of test"}       
     ]
  }
}
```

this json should be sent to the backend and saved, so a mobile app can ask for those information and display them in a customized way. Maintaining elements' order is crucial.

So, how can i obtain the above structure from innerHTML in javascript? I'm madding out on it

Comment: Well, your object isn't valid.. your have the `text` key twice

Comment: _Maintaining elements' order is crucial_ Then you'll need to use an array. Will also help with what @tymeJV said

Comment: @tymeJV Updated the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this might give you a basic idea:

1) You need to select different keys for start text and end text like start_text and end_text.

2) Create a virtual DOM element and store the innerHTML string you have in the innerHTML of DOM element. This will help you to access DOM methods and you can achieve what you want.
Ex:

```
var content = '(innerHTML content)';
var d = document.createElement("DIV");
d.innerHTML = content;
var p_tags = d.querySelectorAll("p");
```

3) Create your preferred object structure.
Ex:

```
var final_content = {};
final_content["page_1"] = {};
final_content["page_1"]["content"] = [];
final_content["page_1"]["content"].push({"start_text":""});
```

4) Finally, you can convert object to JSON string with JSON.stringify(final_content).

Comment: Nice input to clarify. I think that i'm able to do it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the format never changes, you can try converting `innerHTML` to string, then split by `</p>`. This will create an array of 4 elements.  Loop through each element. For strings, stripping tags from strings can easily be done with `string.replace("<p>","")`. For the more complicated `iframe` and `audio` tags, use this regex `"(https.*?)"`. It will return the src url. Then create your objects with those values.
Here's some quick pseudo code:

```
var aHtml = JSON.stringify(element.innerHTML).split('</p>');


var result = [];
aHtml.forEach(function(item, idx, arr){
    // run regex against it, grab matching element
    var match = item.match(/"(https.*?)"/,"g");
    if(match){
        var url = match[1]; // the url
        if(match[0].indexOf('audio')> -1){
            result.push({audio: url});      
        }else{
            result.push({video: url});
        }
        
    }else{
        var str = item.replace(/(<p>|<br>)/g, " ");
        result.push({text: str});
    }
})

console.log(result);
```